# maps in $L^2(X,\mu, \mathbb{H}) $

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, measurable-functions

I was attempting to solve part $b$ of the following problem from Michael Reed's Functional Analysis book. I got stuck a little bit. I guess in here a "basis" means what it means in linear algebra so $\{\phi_k\}$ is not necessarily am orthogonal basis.

Note that in this book $(\gamma.a,\lambda.b) = \bar{\gamma} . \lambda . (a,b) $

Here's what I've got:

$\begin{align} g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(\phi_k, g(x)).\phi_k} 
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{((\sum_{l = 1}^{\infty}{(e_l, \phi_k). e_l)}, g(x))).(\sum_{l = 1}^{\infty}{(e_l, \phi_k). e_l)}}
\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(\sum_{l = 1}^{\infty}{(\phi_k, e_l)(e_l, g(x))}).(\sum_{l = 1}^{\infty}{(e_l, \phi_k). e_l)}}
\end{align}$

but got nothing more. Should I really use the fact that $g$ belongs to $L^2(X,\mu,\mathbb{H})$?

If so, I guess I have to make some orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{H}$ with the aid of $\{\phi_k\}$s, and again if so, how should I?

Are $\{\phi_k\}$s orthogonal in the first place?

Thank you for your attention.

[image]

Comment: What I know is I've gotta somehow prove that: $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(e_k, g(x)).e_k} $ is equal to the some in the right hand side. which is: $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(\phi_k, g(x)).\phi_k} $

Comment: Suppose for a certain $g$ and $x$ that $g(x) = \phi_m$ for some $m$. It is claiming that $$\sum_k (\phi_k, \phi_m)\phi_k = \phi_m$$ which implies $(\phi_k, \phi_m) = \delta_{k,m}$ for all $k, m$. I.e, by "basis" here, they mean "orthonormal basis". As for your comment, that is not what you have to show. There is no "$e_k$" defined or assumed here. The basis you are given is $\phi_k$. This is not $\Bbb R^n$ where there is a canonical basis you can fall back on.

Comment: @paul-sinclair By gram smith you can make orthogonal $e_i$ s. Why does that imply $\phi_k$ s are orthogonal. I think It's not obvious for me. We shold be careful with series here. Stuff like rearranging may not hold here.

Comment: Yes, you can define $e_i$, but that is the point: YOU have to define them. You cannot just pull them out of your posterior and use them without explaining what they are. You can just say "if $\{e_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis, ...", since any inner product space has orthonormal bases. But you only can use *canonical* symbolry without introducing it, and it is only for $\Bbb R^n, \Bbb C^n$ that "$\{e_i\}$" is canonical.

Comment: $(\phi_k, \phi_m) = \delta_{k,m}$ is the definition of orthonormal. The statement that   $\sum_k (\phi_k, \phi_m)\phi_k = \phi_m$ by definition means exactly the same thing as $\sum_k^N (\phi_k, \phi_m)\phi_k \to \phi_m$ as $N \to \infty$, as per your book. That this implies $(\phi_k, \phi_m) = \delta_{k,m}$ follows from the definition of a basis ([Schauder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) or [Hamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis)). It does not depend on reordering.